# Rails Inflections and STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti

Not sure if this is the inflection or STI.

I have a model `Activity` which I have another class `Integrity` inherited through STI.  In that model I have this:

```
class Integrity < Activity

  def self.model_name
    Activity.model_name
  end

end
```

which I have seen to help with routing under STI.

I set my routes:

```
  resources :integrity, controller: :activities, type: 'Integrity'
```

and inflections:

```
   inflect.plural 'integrity', 'integrity'
   inflect.singular 'integrity', 'integrity'
   inflect.irregular 'integrity', 'integrity'
```

That seems to work:

```
>> url_for [:new, :integrity]
=> "/integrity/new"
```

except for the index route:

```
>> url_for [:integrity]
!! #<ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"activities", :type=>"Integrity"}, missing required keys: [:id]>
```

but this works:

```
>> url_for [:integrity, :index]
=> "/integrity"
```

The issue I have is that for 'normal' inflections on my other STI classes I have this:

```
>> url_for [:operations]
=> "/operations"
```

how do I get rails to recognize the `:integrity` as the index route?  I want to have the same view files for all the STI classes and then have a common structure for building dynamic routes etc.  I can't have some needing the extra :index and some not.

Answer (score 0):

when you pass a singular name to `resources`, the `index` route becomes `name_index_path`

in your case `integrity_index_path` or `url_for(:integrity, :index)`

you can add a custom route

```
get "integrity", to: 'activities#index', type: 'Integrity'
resources :integrity, controller: :activities, type: 'Integrity'
```

then you can do `url_for(:integrity)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - posting this in the question would probably have triggered an answer:

I had this:

```
resources :integrity, controller: :activities, type: 'Integrity'
```

when I should have had:

```
resources :integrities, controller: :activities, type: 'Integrity'
```

along with:

```
inflect.irregular 'integrity', 'integrities'
```

I had it in my head that I needed to keep the 'Normal' plural `Integrity` in my app.  This eliminates all the custom routes etc.